# Google Form find editURL from viewform URL (or getPublishedUrl)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form link to submit my response that I DONT OWN (think of it as i need to submit my response on this form regularly) sample link here https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeZfR4Di9yfTDc5yXc7WYmLy-MjwVf_XLC7_ZeQ7367Yh2DpQ/viewform

I need to find the edit URL for the link like this https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1R_Ddx4-BNpnCwRJYQcWxnBJVd0SzvsJDisg2qu41fpU/edit using code.

I DONT want to use any excel etc as i just need to retrieve the editURL. Whats the best way to do it.

When i try below code, it gives me

> "**Exception: No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because you have not edited this item or you do not have permission to access it.**

I also tried using `formID` but same issue. Can you help?

```
function run() {
    var form = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeZfR4Di9yfTDc5yXc7WYmLy-MjwVf_XLC7_ZeQ7367Yh2DpQ/formResponse');

    Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
    Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be an *Owner* or *Editor* of the form to be able to get the `editURL` property of the form using the code you posted.

If you are *not* an Owner or Editor of this form (or a Super Admin in your Google Workspace Domain), there is no way for you to know the `editURL` of the form.